# How to get subtensor by irregular index?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to get sub-tensor by irregular index.
Here is my question.

```
Input tensor = 2x8x10x1(Batch x Height x Width x Channel)

index_Height = [0,1,4,5]

index_Width = [0,1,4,5,8,9]

Output_tensor = 2x4x6x1
```

How can I get this result?

Here is my python version:

```
input_np = np.zeros((2,8,10,1))
nx, ny = (10, 8)
x = np.linspace(0, 9, nx)
y = np.linspace(0, 7,  ny)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x , y)
input_np[0,:,:,0] = xv
input_np[1,:,:,0] = yv

index_Height = [0,1,4,5]
index_Width  = [0,1,4,5,8,9]

output_np = input_np[:,index_Height][:,:,index_Width]
```

How can I do this on tensorflow? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `tf.gather()` twice.

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputtensor = tf.constant(input_np)
height_tensor = tf.gather(inputtensor,index_Height,axis=1)
output_tensor = tf.gather(height_tensor,index_Width,axis=2)
print(output_tensor.shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    output_tensor_val = sess.run(output_tensor)
    print((output_tensor_val==output_np).all())

(2, 4, 6, 1)
True
```