# tf gather each element in batch with different indices

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I [gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) different elements from a minibatch by different indices?
e.g.
for the following(`mini_batch=3`) tensor:

```
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]
  [12 13 14 15]]

 [[16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]
  [24 25 26 27]
  [28 29 30 31]]

 [[32 33 34 35]
  [36 37 38 39]
  [40 41 42 43]
  [44 45 46 47]]]
```

with the indices

```
[[[0 0]
  [2 0]
  [1 0]
  [0 2]
  [2 2]
  [1 2]
  [0 1]
  [2 1]
  [1 1]]

 [[0 0]
  [3 0]
  [1 0]
  [0 3]
  [2 3]
  [1 3]
  [0 1]
  [3 1]
  [1 1]]

 [[0 0]
  [3 0]
  [1 0]
  [0 3]
  [2 3]
  [1 3]
  [0 1]
  [3 1]
  [1 1]]]
```

I would like the result to be

```html
[[[ 0  1    3]
  [ 4  5    7]
  [12 13   15]]

 [[16 17  19]
  [20 21  23]
  [28 29  31]]

 [[32 33 34 ]
  [36 37 38 ]
  [40 41 42 ]]
```

But using the following code:

```
tf.gather_nd(batch_input,batch_indecies)
```

I get the following output

```
indices[1,8] = [3, 3] does not index into param shape [3,4,4] [Op:GatherNd]
```

From my understanding, for the index `[[[0,0]]]` tf gets the first batch, first row, i.e `[0,1,2,3]` when I instead want to get the `[0]` from the first batch.

Here's how I managed to do that(I still slice and stack, and concat the trailing batch index to each index, hence I think a better solution is out there):

```
def gather_by_batch(tensor, batch_indecies):  # e.g shapes (4,10,10) (4,3,3) 
    #working
    per_dim_shape = tf.shape(batch_indecies)[1]
    stacked_indecies = tf.split(batch_indecies, FLAGS.batch_size)

    final_indecies =[]
    for idx,indecies in enumerate(stacked_indecies):
        final_indecies.append(tf.concat([tf.broadcast_to([idx], [per_dim_shape*per_dim_shape, 1]), indecies], axis=1))

    return tf.reshape(tf.gather_nd(tensor, final_indecies), (-1, per_dim_shape, per_dim_shape))
```

Comment: Could you share a more copy/paste firendly version of the arrays? (including commas)

Comment: I've added the code (used Jupiter and eager execution to the question

Comment: I don't understand entirely what you are trying. Your data tensor has shape `(3, 4, 4)`, the indices `(3, 9, 2)` and the expected result is `(3, 3, 3)`. How are these three connected exactly? Are the first nine pairs of indices suppose to index into the first `(4, 4)` subtensor? If that is the case, for example `[2 0]` and `[0 2]` would correspond to values `8` and `2`, right? But neither of those are in the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56140858/how-to-get-subtensor-by-irregular-index

Comment: @jdehesa I'm trying to gather different indices from each element in the minibatch. I have 3 9X2 indices arrays, each correspond to a gather operation in a different element in the minibatch

Comment: @jdehesa I've added my code that managed to do that with concatenating the per gather index, maybe now the goal is clearer